# Is it possible to create an external hive table on a parquet file with a different schema?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have my parquet files structured as follows:

```
+------+------------------+------------------+
| col1 |       col2       |        col3      |
+------+------------------+------------------+
|  v0  | { k1:v1, k2:v2 } | { k3:v3, k4:v4 } |
+------+------------------+------------------+
```

col2 and col3 are map columns.
And I wish to create a hive table with the below schema on top of this as follows:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| col1  |  k1 |  k2 |  k3 |  k4 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  v0   |  v1 |  v2 |  v3 |  v4 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Is it possible to create the above mapping? I'm familiar with a similar process for creating an external table on a hbase table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with the next steps:

1.Create a temporary table and store the file like it is (with map column type);

2.Create a second table with the final structure that you need;

3.Insert from the temporary table into the second table. When you insert you need to use some functions like: trim, split etc. You can use [this example](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222388/hive-split-for-columns.html).